# Multiple nodes and replication in elasticsearch, to have optimistic performance

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I am trying to connect multiple nodes in elastic search with 5 nodes.
2 nodes as master nodes and 3 as data nodes.

any effect if I use the replication as 2? performance will be good or not?

Answer (score 0):

First of all avoid keeping 2 master nodes, as it would be vulnerable to [split brain problem](http://blog.trifork.com/2013/10/24/how-to-avoid-the-split-brain-problem-in-elasticsearch/).

**How many will be efficient ?**

Number of master/data nodes highly depends on your use case with the cluster. Try getting answers to questions like:

1. Is your cluster index-heavy, search-heavy or both ?
2. How much data are you doing to index, and with what frequency ?
3. How many search request hits are you expecting ?

**how to coordinate them**

You don't need to. Elasticsearch's nodes are capable of doing so. Just ensure your elasticsearch.yml has all the node IPs mentioned (Under unicast hosts, I would prefer to avoid multicast). Use a configuration like this:

```
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false 
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["<node1-ip:port>", "<node2-ip:port>", "<node3-ip:port>", "<node4-ip:port>"]
```

**any effect if I use the replication as 2**

Adding replicas would increase disk usage and heap size too. For 4 nodes, replication factor of 1 should be enough, unless you need high redundancy.

Because you've added spring-data-elasticsearch as a tag, I am assuming you want to use it as a Transport client with Elasticsearch. Check out [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/first-step-spring-boot-and) to get started.

Comment: So, can you say, 1 master node and 3 data nodes would be ok? if I need index-heavy and search-heavy @Utkarsh Mishra

Comment: Try keeping 3 master nodes (with relatively low RAM), and 3 master nodes (with more RAM), as they take most part of the heap.

Comment: Is it 3 master nodes and 3 data nodes you mentioned @Utkarsh Mishra

Comment: Yes!
Make sure that your `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` settings are correct. In this case, it should be 2.

Comment: @coding-bug Trying the solution ? Would appreciate an upvote if it works :)
Helps other too.